# Nexenta Solaris starting

Tags: solaris, boot, opensolaris

I have installed Nexanta Solaris with VMWare, but it boots to command line. Any idea how to bring up the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.nexenta.org/projects/site/wiki/FAQ#head-b8cf5cd2fbc8f9983c22346f7c67d4b5752b0ace):

> Cannot find `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` after installation...
>
> Similar to Solaris Express, `xorg.conf` is not present. If you want to customize the file, the best way is to boot in single-user mode, run:

```
Xorg -configure
```

> Then copy `/root/xorg.conf.new` over to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and begin your customizations. Once you exit the console, the system will resume to multi-user level and GDM will start.

Comment: Thats right! Afterwards we also need to install gnome by using the command sudo apt-get install gnome-core.